# Do I need to cast unsigned chars?

Tags: c++, windows, casting

I'm using

```
unsigned char ucONE = (unsigned char)1;
```

as a global variable.

Is this necessary?

Comment: What are you using it for? If you share the code that uses it, we can tell you if it's necessary or not

Comment: That's not the proper naming convention for globals. You'll want to prefix the declaration with a `//` as per [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/coding-standards#global-vars).

Comment: BTW, this is a C style cast; for C++ you should use `static_cast<unsigned char>(1)` if necessary. However, [casts are best avoided](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/style-and-techniques#static-cast).

Answer (score 4):

No, integral types (which include the 3 types `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char`) can be implicitly converted to each other. As this behavior may not always be intended however, several compilers issue warnings, and some code conventions require casts to make conversions explicit.

In any case, *if* you cast, you should prefer the C++ cast operators, because they're more limited and thus safer. In your case, this could be `static_cast`.

As already hinted by others, global variables are not always the best practice and a variable (not constant) named "one" with the value 1 is slightly suspicious, but without knowing your design it's difficult to tell whether those choices are appropriate.